# Adding multiple vector layers into GeoJSON file

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, geojson

I have multiple polygons stored in a list like this :

```
def drawParcel(self, propriete):
    length = len(propriete.name)
    i = 0
    while i < length:
       layer = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon', propriete.name[i], "memory")
       allLayers.append(layer)
```

I have tried this code but i only get in the json file the last element of my list :

```
uri ="C:/Users/ilyasse2.0/Documents/SQRLAND/ils.json"  
context = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()  
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()  
options.driverName = "GeoJson"  
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(allLayers[0],uri,context,options) 

#switch mode to append layer instead of overwriting the file  
options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer 
for layer in allLayers:
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(layer,uri,context,options)
```

How can i create a GeoJSON file with the list of layers ?

Comment: GeoJSON only has a single "layer" - you will need to combine the features and then write them to the GeoJSON

Comment: thank you i just need somehow to get all the features of my layers (points,polygons and lines) and put them into geojson right ? is there any solution to this ?

Comment: I wonder if your code runs QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer for each layer that you want to append.

Comment: Have you tried with `options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.AppendToLayerNoNewFields`?